# Keeping Email Message from Grouping into Conversation View in Gmail

Tags: smtp, gmail

I'm working on a feature for a client to send them email updates whenever a specific event occurs on their site.  When the message shows up in Gmail, the messages get grouped together in conversation view even through they aren't the same conversation.  It appears that this is due to the fact that [Gmail groups based only on the subject](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16095/35772).  The client is adamant that we not change the subject line (don't get me started).

Does anyone know how I can disable this by sending a special header in the mail or am I out of luck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force emails not to be grouped into conversations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434110/force-emails-not-to-be-grouped-into-conversations)

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no way to prevent this, short of turning off conversation view (have you considered that?).

My guess is that Gmail is actually threading based on its own `Thread-Topic` header field, which it adds (overwriting any value you pass; it just copies the Subject field) - there's no way of telling, though, unless you can change that field after the fact.  Which leads to the suggestion of writing an IMAP application to download the message, edit the headers, and re-upload it again.  You'd need to investigate the feasibility of this, though.